# Use Spring 3 filters to embed timestamp in resource paths?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-3

Would it work to setup some filters using Spring 3 MVC where the paths for javascript files and css files are modified when streamed to the client, by embedding some timestamp in the filename. And then when those resources are later requested another filter then strips those timestamps out?

This would be an attempt to prevent problems of cached js/css files when an application is redeployed

What would I need to do to set this up? How do I setup the filter to replace the paths with a timestamp and then how to I setup the filter to later strp the timestamps out?

I just need info on the Spring 3 MVC configuration for it in the web.xml, I am ok with what the actual code in the filter will need to do

Answer (score 1):

It may be simpler to use Spring's resource mapping `<mvc:resources>`, that maps a virtual path to the real location of your CSS and Javascript files. The virtual path can contain the version of your application. This means that when you deploy a new version of your application, the path of the CSS and Javascript that gets sent to the browser is different than before and this fools the browser into thinking that they're new resources - and so it reloads them.

For example to map CSS and Javascript files in /resources:

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources" mapping="/resources-1.2.0/**"/>
```

This says that any request that comes in with the URL pattern /resources-1.2.0 followed by anything (e.g. /resources-1.2.0/css/styles.css), look for the file in the folder named **resources** in the web root.

When you update the application version between deployments the virtual path to the CSS and Javascript resources will change and so browsers will be forced to reload the files - even though the real files are in the same old location.

You can make the application version dynamic too - so you don't need to modify your config file.

There's a more in-depth write up of this whole approach [here](http://techblog.troyweb.com/index.php/2012/05/preventing-browsers-from-caching-resources-with-spring-3-sort-of/).